# Durandal 2.0 router can you replace # for #! for ajax web crawling purposes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, single-page-application, durandal

Is it possible to replace the default router behavior in Durandal 2.0 to replace the default route for example: 'mysite.com/#/myroute' with 'mysite.com/#!/myroute' the reason being is that in order for the google spider to detect the page is ajax crawl-able, i need to insert a hashbang in the url not just a hashtag. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, in Durandal 2.0 you are not able to do this. The `router` and `history` plugin do not support this, and it would not be an easy fix since there are some places in the code that rely on the `#`.

However, I don't think this is a problem in your scenario. Maybe you need to change the way to deal with the requirement of making your application crawlable.

You still can make your application SEO compatible using `#`by specifying the meta fragment type in the main HTML of the application:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

So you are telling google that your links don't have the `#!`but that the application is using JavaScript rendering. Then the requests from the crawler will include 
`?_escaped_fragment_`.

So in your app you will use:

```
mysite.com/#myroute
```

and the crawler will request:

```
mysite.com?_escaped_fragment_=myroute
```

Check the Section 3 of Google's [documentation on crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) to know more about the meta fragment tag.

**SUGGESTION**

If you want to fully take advantage of this feature I suggest using pushState in Durandal 2.0 by activating the router like this:

```
router.activate({ pushState: true } );
```

And  also including the meta fragment tag.

```
 <meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

**Things you should consider if using pushState:**

- Use pushState only if you are not planning to support old browsers.
- You need to make your server side pushState ready, this means that when the server is requested with `mysite.com/myroute`**should be able to return the same JS application and let the client process  the query string parameters**. For example, this can be achieved using IIS URL rewrite if you are using ASP.NET. There's a good [blog post](http://tarkus.me/post/32121691785/angularjs-with-asp-net-mvc-4) about this topic.

Comment: Excellent clearly written response. Thank you, this will help me greatly.

Comment: I have a quick question, I think ive got this working now but when I submit my site to google, and give links to google do I need to give it http://mysite.com/#! or just http://mysite.com and google will add in the _escaped_fragment_ because I have it in the meta tag?